# Read RDF:foaf file with Apache Jena

Tags: jena, java-ee-7, foaf

I have a problem with reading RDF file, which is using foaf tags. I would like to read it with Apache Jena. Below is the snippet of the RDF file.

```xml
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://test.example.com/"     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"     xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/">
<foaf:Person rdf:about="http://test.example.com/MainPerson.rdf">
<foaf:firstName>John</foaf:firstName>
<foaf:lastName>Doe</foaf:lastName>
<foaf:nick>Doe</foaf:nick>
<foaf:gender>Male</foaf:gender>
<foaf:based_near>Honolulu</foaf:based_near>
<foaf:birthday>08-14-1990</foaf:birthday>
<foaf:mbox>john@example.com</foaf:mbox>
<foaf:homepage rdf:resource="http://www.example.com"/>
<foaf:img rdf:resource="http://weknowmemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/wat-meme.jpg"/>
<foaf:made>
Article: Developing applications in Java
</foaf:made>
<foaf:age>24</foaf:age>
<foaf:interest>
Java, Java EE (web tier), PrimeFaces, MySQL, PHP, OpenCart, Joomla,   Prestashop, CSS3, HTML5
</foaf:interest>
<foaf:pastProject rdf:resource="http://www.supercombe.si"/>
<foaf:status>Student</foaf:status>
<foaf:geekcode>M+, L++</foaf:geekcode>
<foaf:knows>
<foaf:Person>
<rdfs:seeAlso rdf:resource="http://test.example.com/Person.rdf"/>
</foaf:Person>
</foaf:knows>
<foaf:knows>
<foaf:Person>
<rdfs:seeAlso rdf:resource="http://test.example.com/Person2.rdf"/>
</foaf:Person>
</foaf:knows>
<foaf:knows>
<foaf:Person>
<rdfs:seeAlso rdf:resource="http://test.example.com/Person3.rdf"/>
</foaf:Person>
</foaf:knows>
</foaf:Person>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I just don't understand how to read this data with Apache Jena in regular POJO object. Any help will be appreciated (couldn't find tutorial on the web for this kind of parsing).

Comment: "read this data with Apache Jena in regular POJO object"  It's not clear what you want to do.  An RDF document is a set of triples.  With Jena, you read an RDF document as a Model object.  What is it that you're trying to get?

Comment: I would like to read the content of the RDF file above, and store the content of the triples in regular pojo class (Object Person, with setters and getters) for later usage (showing data on frontend).  The biggest problem i have is parsing this RDF file (reading from RDF file and writing to RDF file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your problem. But if you need to read RDF file to a POJO object, you have a lot of choice. For example, you can read your rdf file using Jena to a model, and then create POJO objects using the methods proposed by the framework to get the values of your properties. 
This is a code example that extracts the `foaf:firstName` from your file

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;

public class Test {
    //First, create a Jena model and use FileManager to read the file
    public static Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       //Use FileManager to read the file and add it to the Jena model
        FileManager.get().readModel(model, "test.rdf");
       //Apply methods like getResource, getProperty, listStatements,listLiteralStatements ...
       //to your model to extract the information you want
        Resource person = model.getResource("http://test.example.com/MainPerson.rdf");
        Property firstName = model.createProperty("http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/firstName");
        String firstNameValue = person.getProperty(firstName).getString();
        System.out.println(firstNameValue);

    }
}
```

You can use those methods in the setters of your POJO class. You can find a very good introduction [here](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html)

Comment: Thank you very much Hatim. This solution was very helpful. Best regards

Comment: Welcome @Salko :) if this solution helped you, you can tag it as an answer, 
Bests